# avoid mongodb js shell checking on _id

Tags: mongodb

if we use the shell to create a collection.it create _id automatically.

And I really DON'T need _id. I getting around this through pymongo using manipulate=False.

when I update multi docs it complains

"""multi-update requires all modified objects to have an _id"""

This is really annoying.Should I give up on the shell or there's a way getting around this?

And unfortunately pymongo seems doesn't support cursor.foreach() yet.

Comment: Why can't you use `_id` as the primary key, instead of another field you've created? You can also have more than one key. `_id` is an important aspect of using MongoDb. Operationally, you may find that using a switch to not validate documents may cause all sorts of subtle issues, and in some hosting environments may not be an option at all. I'd suggest you conform your schema to MongoDb's design, or just ignore the extra field.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's an integral part of how a unique hash represents a data set in a database.

Besides I think it's not possible (and shouldn't be, without a very valid reason).

From [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/):

> In MongoDB, documents stored in a collection require a unique _id
>   field that **acts as a primary key**. Because ObjectIds are small, most
>   likely unique, and fast to generate, MongoDB uses ObjectIds as the
>   default value for the _id field if the _id field is not specified.
>   **MongoDB clients should add an _id field** with a unique ObjectId.
>   However, if a client does not add an _id field, **mongod will add an _id**
>   field that holds an ObjectId.

So even if you avoid the shell from adding the _id, the mongod should be adding it.

Comment: Actually.I have another primary key.and mongodb server works just fine without _id.The server allow docs without _id.

Comment: I think using the flag [--noobjcheck](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongod/#cmdoption--noobjcheck), while starting mongod might just work.

Answer (score 1):

You ***have to have*** an `_id` - if you dont provide one mongod will add one - so theres no avoiding it.  If you have another primary key - then use that as the `_id` - it just has to be unique and immutable.

In pymongo or *any other* driver if you don't add a `_id` it will generally add one for you - in pymongo `manipulate=False` means that pymongo won't add the `_id` but mongod still will:

```
>>> import pymongo
>>> conn = pymongo.MongoClient()
>>> db = conn["test"]
>>> db.drop_collection("test")
>>> db.test.insert({"a": 123}, manipulate=False)
[None]
>>> db.test.find_one()
{u'a': 123, u'_id': ObjectId('51dfbfe13eb39b26159bd56b')}
```

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB *can* be told to not make an _id but this WILL break replication and quite a few other things that rely on the `_id` to not do full table scans etc. Even though MongoDB does kind of allow it elsewhere (mainly due to bugs) the option to strip the `_id` field should only be used on capped collections to avoid serious performance problems when exapanding.

I also would not recommend setting `--noobjcheck` unless you want to loose something quite integral to ensuring consistency of your documents.